# (pyqt5) how can i set the value for QPrinter.setMargins(self, QPagedPaintDevice.Margins)?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have problem with the default page margins.

I want to set the page margins all 0 and I did.

but it has always approximately 1 inch margins and I thought the hardware or some default values are keep the left and top margins.

So I called the function QPrinter.margins().left and top, and they return 4.23

I don't know what the floats mean but I assume they have to be 0 for achieve my expectation.

Here are codes i used.

please look this and give me some advice.

thank you.

```
def printPreview(self):
    self.hide()
    self.text = QTextEdit()
    self.text.setHtml("HTML BODY")
    printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Landscape)
    # print(printer.margins(), printer.margins().left, printer.margins().top) <-- it says it has already some margins
    # printer.setMargins(QtGui.QPagedPaintDevice) <-- this one is pain in the ass
    previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self.text)
    previewDialog.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview2)
    previewDialog.exec_()
    self.close()

def printPreview2(self, printer):
    self.text.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Try it: `printer.setPageMargins(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0)`

Comment: @S.Nick thx but it doesn't change anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print margins less that the minimum page margins you also need to `.setFullPath(True)`.

```
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setPageMargins(0,0,0,0, QPrinter.Millimeter)
```

The Qt5 docs suggest have the following signature

```
printer.setPageMargins(QMarginF(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

[This bug report against Qt5](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32987) says that you must also set the margins before attaching the printer to a painter — although I think your code is doing this correctly.

Comment: Sorry, `printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(0,0,0,0))`  `TypeError: setPageMargins(self, float, float, float, float, QPrinter.Unit): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QMarginsF'`

Comment: @S. Nick is that in pyqt5? I only see the QMarginF in the Qt5 docs.

Comment: @mfitzp thank you for your answer. im using pyqt5 and I got error exactly same with Nick. And I did the first recommendation but it does not change anything for me